# Getting "System.logW: No Compatibility callbacks set! Querying change 119147584" Warning when Unit-Testing Kotlin App

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, sharedpreferences, robolectric

I wrote a Unit-test with RobolectricsTestRunner included.

The unit test passed, but with the following warning:

```
System.logW: No Compatibility callbacks set! Querying change 119147584
```

All I did in the unit-test, I saved a variable in Shared Preferences.
This warning doesn't destroy anything. I was just wondering what it means.
Unit-Test:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(sdk = [30])
class SharedPreferencesProviderTest {

    private lateinit var sharedPreferencesProvider: SharedPreferencesProviderInterface

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        // setup Shared preferences
        ...

        // Shared Preferences Access
        ...

        // clearing Shared Preferences
       ...
    }

    @Test
    fun firstStart_shouldBeTrueDefaultAndCheckChange() {
        // Default check
        var firstStart =
            sharedPreferencesProvider.getIsFirstStart()
        var expected = true
        assertTrue(firstStart == expected)

        // Check whether it handles changes
        sharedPreferencesProvider.setIsFirstStart(false)
        firstStart =
            sharedPreferencesProvider.getIsFirstStart()
        expected = false
        assertTrue(firstStart == expected)
    }}
```

I seems like it doesn't trigger OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener anymore, but I'm not sure. [source](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/reference/compat-framework-changes?hl=pl)

Comment: I am having the same issue when running unit tests using robolectric

Comment: I got this when setting includeAndroidResources to true in order to inflate a layout. It was prefaced by this error ```[WARN] Unknown chunk type '200'.```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: You can ignore that.

The log comes from `android.compat.Compatibility.BehaviorChangeDelegate`. This is an interface class for behaviour change listener.

The default action of the `isChangeEnabled` function call, as stated below, is to print the log and return `true`.

```java
        @SystemApi(client = MODULE_LIBRARIES)
        default boolean isChangeEnabled(long changeId) {
            // Do not use String.format here (b/160912695)
            System.logW("No Compatibility callbacks set! Querying change " + changeId);
            return true;
        }
```

What I assume is that during the Robolectric test runs, an implementation of this class that does not override the `isChangeEnabled` is some how attached and invoked. It's unclear where it's happening (I searched through the robolectric repo but I assume the repo isn't the culprit), and how we can fix this - or even if we need to fix this.

If you are just curious if you've done something wrong, no it's not you. You can just ignore this log.